# How can I get the selected option of the closest element of my clicked box?

Tags: jquery, select, closest

I want to alert the selected `vat` option of the container where I clicked the box. But I get an undefined result:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.box', function(event) {
  var result = $(this).closest('.container').find('.vat').find("option:selected").val();
  alert(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr class='container'>
  <td>
    <div class="box">box1</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select class='vat'>
      <option value='0'>0 %</option>
      <option selected value='7'>7 %</option>
      <option value='19'>19 %</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr class='container'>
  <td>
    <div class="box">box2</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select class='vat'>
      <option value='0'>0 %</option>
      <option value='7'>7 %</option>
      <option selected value='19'>19 %</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jQuery code works fine, the issue is because your HTML is invalid. You're missing the `<table />` element around the `tr`, so the layout is broken when rendered.

Note however than you don't need `.find('option:selected')` as you can get the `val()` straight form the `select` element. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.box', function(event) {
  var result = $(this).closest('.container').find('.vat').val();
  alert(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr class='container'>
    <td>
      <div class="box">box1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class='vat'>
        <option value='0'>0 %</option>
        <option selected value='7'>7 %</option>
        <option value='19'>19 %</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='container'>
    <td>
      <div class="box">box2</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class='vat'>
        <option value='0'>0 %</option>
        <option value='7'>7 %</option>
        <option selected value='19'>19 %</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```